# Css transition-property: transform only?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I would like to animate sidebar with CSS transition

```
.site-config
  flex: 0 1 0
  overflow: hidden
  transform: translateX(100%)
  transition: all .4s ease-in
  &.active
    flex: 2 1 40%
    transform: translateX(0)
```

It works well, but because flex is also under transition, it slows down appearance and causes other performance issues.

Eventually, I tried `transition: transform .5s ease` but it's not working.

**Update**

Currently `transition: transform` works, but quite unepected from time to time.
Short video reference
http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cDlDYKQZCY

Comment: `transition: all` is slow, and you should target exactly what you're trying to transition. If you're still having performance issues try moving from `translateX` to `translate3d`. If hardware acceleration is enabled it should improve performance.

Comment: @Press Isn't X is just an shortcut for 3d ? I think translate is GPU accelerated as well. That's how it work with translate now, quite unexpected. Im not sure why http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cDlDYKQZCY

Comment: IIRC X is shorthand for translate(x,y) and is still 2D so no acceleration.

Comment: You are right, it's performing much better. I didn''t know about that. Still a bit buggy, but maybe it's just my MB problem )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments you should try to avoid using `transition: all` as it can slow down performance. Try to be as specific as possible with your transitions.

Also, move your transition from 2D to 3D by using `translate3d(x,y,z)` instead of `translateX(x)` to make use of hardware acceleration when enabled/available.